# Spring @Transactional does not override superclass

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, transactions

I have the following scenario, whereby I have an abstract superclass as a service that has a method annotated with `@Transactional`. In only one subclass I want to annotate that method to use a specific transaction manager. However, when I step through the code, it still seems to use the transaction manager specified in the superclass.

I checked into the behavior of `@Transactional` and it is annotated with `@Inherited`. However, the Java documentation states that in this case the annotation gets checked in the lowest class in the hierarchy and then the next highest and up the line.

So per this my later `@Transactional` should be what is being used. But it isn't so I am trying to find out if there is some other mechanism at play.

**Code**

```
public abstact class SuperService {
   @Transactional
   public void save () {
      // Do some work
   }
}

public class SubService extends SuperService {
   @Override
   @Transactional("specialTransactionManager") // <-- This never gets used
   public void save () {
      // Do some work
   }
}
```